# Auth0 call back giving 404 error

Tags: php, oauth, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2, auth0

I have implemented an auth0 social authentication in my project. My problem is when I try to login, I am getting error shown in the image. I have tried this code using wamp server, it is working fine but now I have to implement it in IIS server. can any body please help me how to fix this error.

[image: Error after redirect]

Comment: please include some code

Comment: I am not sure about which code to show here.  It's just simple app. I follow https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/php/01-authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have put mime type php on the iis
check if default document is set